# shopify api returns status code 400 Bad Request with my php codeigniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopify

am able to update product title successfully but when i try making a request to shopify api to update my product image alt i keeps getting status code 400 Bad Request ... here is my code below ... I would be thankful for any help

```
    public function alt(){

    function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $data = array(); //Always define $data in the constructor to make it available throughout your code
        }

    //getting shop info to access the app
    $store_name = $this->session->userdata('store_name');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('Store');
    $storeinfo_data=$this->Store->load_store_info($store_name);
    $store_name_db = $storeinfo_data->store_name;
    $store_name_tk = $storeinfo_data->access_token;
    $store_name_url = $storeinfo_data->myshopify_domain;
    $this->data['storeinfo']=$storeinfo_data;               




    if($store_name == $store_name_db){

        //authenticating app with shopify api to be alble to access shop info
    $sc = new ShopifyClient($store_name_url, $store_name_tk, SHOPIFY_KEY, SHOPIFY_SECRET);

    //making a GET request to shopify api for shop products 
    $shop_products = $sc->call('GET', '/admin/products.json', null);

    foreach($shop_products as $product) {
        $product_id = $product['id'];
        $product_d = $sc->call('GET', '/admin/products/' . $product_id . '/images.json', null);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($product_d);
        $position =  "1";
        $key = "alt";
        $value = "new alt tag content";

        $metafields =  array(
            "key"=>"alt",
            "value"=>"new alt tag content",
            "value_type"=>"string",
            "namespace"=>"tags"
        );

        $image = array(
            "id"=> "16827152131",
            "position" => 1, 
            "metafields"=>$metafields
        );

        //making a request to update image alt of a product in shop 
        try{
            $shop_product = $sc->call('PUT','/admin/products/8445495491/images/16827152131.json', $image);
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            echo '<pre>'; 
                print_r($e);

        }
        exit();





    }



    }else{

    }


}
```

and here is the output i get

```
ShopifyApiException Object
(
[method:protected] => PUT
[path:protected] => /admin/products/8445495491/images/16827152131.json
[params:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16827152131
        [position] => 1
        [metafields] => Array
            (
                [key] => alt
                [value] => new alt tag content
                [value_type] => string
                [namespace] => tags
            )

    )

[response_headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [http_status_code] => 400
        [http_status_message] => Bad Request
        [server] => nginx
        [date] => Mon, 26 Sep 2016 09:11:59 GMT
        [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
        [transfer-encoding] => chunked
        [connection] => keep-alive
        [x-frame-options] => DENY
        [x-shopid] => 14690858
        [x-shardid] => 2
        [x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit] => 1/40
        [http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit] => 1/40
        [x-stats-userid] => 0
        [x-stats-apiclientid] => 1423954
        [x-stats-apipermissionid] => 31527902
        [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block; report=/xss-report/9729121a-c8c6-4ff2-aee8-cb9963cd864f?source%5Baction%5D=update&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproduct_images&source%5Bsection%5D=admin
        [x-request-id] => 9729121a-c8c6-4ff2-aee8-cb9963cd864f
        [x-dc] => ash
        [x-download-options] => noopen
        [x-permitted-cross-domain-policies] => none
        [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
    )

[response:protected] => Array
    (
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [image] => Required parameter missing or invalid
            )

    )

[message:protected] => Bad Request
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 400
[file:protected] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newp/application/libraries/shopify/shopify.class.php
[line:protected] => 70
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newp/application/controllers/platforms/Shopify.php
                [line] => 347
                [function] => call
                [class] => ShopifyClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => PUT
                        [1] => /admin/products/8445495491/images/16827152131.json
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 16827152131
                                [position] => 1
                                [metafields] => Array
                                    (
                                        [key] => alt
                                        [value] => new alt tag content
                                        [value_type] => string
                                        [namespace] => tags
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newp/system/core/CodeIgniter.php
                [line] => 514
                [function] => alt
                [class] => Shopify
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newp/index.php
                [line] => 315
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/newp/system/core/CodeIgniter.php
                    )

                [function] => require_once
            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] =>
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed a few things here. The image data has to be contained in an `{"image": ... }` object and the `metafields` should come as an array. Also, if you are modifying an existing metafield then include the metafield ID in the payload.

Try replacing this:

```
    $image = array(
        "id"=> "16827152131",
        "position" => 1, 
        "metafields"=>$metafields
    );
```

with something like this:

```
    $image = array("image" => array(
        "id"=> 16827152131,
        "position" => 1, 
        "metafields"=> $metafields
    ));
```

And replace this:

```
    $metafields =  array(
        "key"=>"alt",
        "value"=>"new alt tag content",
        "value_type"=>"string",
        "namespace"=>"tags"
    );
```

with something like this:

```
    $metafields =  array(array(
        "id"=> 123,
        "key"=>"alt",
        "value"=>"new alt tag content",
        "value_type"=>"string",
        "namespace"=>"tags"
    ));
```

`123` would be the ID of the metafield that you are looking to modify. You can obtain that ID using an API call like this: `GET /admin/metafields.json?metafield[owner_id]=16827152131&metafield[owner_resource]=product_image`

You can find examples of the correct format here: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product_image#update

Hope this helps!